# How to store data into multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know this is a dumb question, but is there a way to produce a code that will display the way I wanted it do like below?:

```
 array()
    0=>
       'label'=> string 'John'
       'start'=>
          array()
             0=> string '2015-01-17'
             1=> string '2015-01-16'
       'end' =>
          array()
             0=> string '2015-01-18'
             1=> string '2015-01-16'
       'class'=>
          array()
             0=> string 'annual'
             1=> string 'sick'
    1=>
       'label'=> string 'Peter'
       'start'=>
          array()
             0=> string '2015-01-02'
       'end' =>
          array()
             0=> string '2015-01-05'
       'class'=>
          array()
             0=> string 'annual'
    2=>
       'label'=> string 'Mark'
       'start'=>
          array()
             0=> string '2015-01-08'
             1=> string '2015-01-09'
       'end' =>
          array()
             0=> string '2015-01-08'
             1=> string '2015-01-09'
       'class'=>
          array()
             0=> string 'sick'
             1=> string 'annual'
```

i have been studying an array lately and i saw a code and modify it to look like this:

```
     $data[] = array(
      'label' => $row["name"] ,
      'start' => array($row["start_date"]), 
      'end'   => array($row["end_date"]),
      'class' => array($row["type"]));
```

and the code displays the following although it's not what I intended it to do.

```
 array (size=6)
 0 => 
  array (size=4)
    'label' => string 'John' (length=4)
    'start' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => string '2015-01-17' (length=10)
   'end' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => string '2015-01-18' (length=10)
   'class' => 
       array (size=1)
        0=> string 'annual' (length=6)
 1 => 
  array (size=4)
    'label' => string 'John' (length=4)
    'start' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => string '2015-01-16' (length=10)
    'end' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 =>string '2015-01-16' (length=10)
    'class' => 
       array (size=1)
        0=>string 'sick' (length=4)
 2 => 
  array (size=4)
    'label' => string 'Peter' (length=5)
    'start' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => string '2015-01-02' (length=10)
     'end' => 
       array (size=1)
         0 => string '2015-01-05' (length=10)
     'class' => 
       array (size=1)
        0=>string 'sick' (length=4)
3 => 
  array (size=4)
    'label' => string 'Mark' (length=19)
    'start' => 
      array (size=1)
       0 => string '2015-01-08' (length=10)
    'end' => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => string '2015-01-08' (length=10)
   'class' => 
       array (size=1)
        0=>string 'sick' (length=4)
4 => 
  array (size=4)
   'label' => string 'Mark' (length=19)
   'start' => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => string '2015-01-09' (length=10)
   'end' => 
     array (size=1)
      0 => string '2015-01-09' (length=10)
   'class' => 
        array (size=1)
        0=>string 'annual' (length=6)
```

Comment: i think you already need to play a little bit of how you manage assigning,, i can see it in your code that you are already close on what you want

Comment: @OliSoproniB.  thank you oli, I have been studying it for weeks but still couldn't sort it out yet.. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try (providing random data)

```
$row['name'] = 'John';
$row['start_date_1'] = '2015-01-01';
$row['start_date_2'] = '2015-01-02';

$row['end_date_1'] = '2015-08-11';
$row['end_date_2'] = '2015-08-22';

$row['class_type_1'] = 'sick';
$row['class_type_2'] = 'annual';

$data[] = array(
  'label' => $row["name"] ,
  'start' => array($row["start_date_1"], $row["start_date_2"]),
  'end'   => array($row["end_date_1"], $row["end_date_2"]),
  'class' => array($row["class_type_1"], $row["class_type_2"]));
```

Also try to avoid strings (I suppose student names) as keys - using student ID would be better (eg, image if the name is changed...)

Comment: thanks for the response. i was wondering what if my start value is more than two?... as i've seen in your example code you manually type array($row["start_date_1"], $row["start_date_2"]),..

Comment: @LBMG What do you mean by start value is more than two? Since I don't know what the two dates eg. '2015-01-17' and '2015-01-16' mean I just assumed semi-random keys.

Comment: the result is like this
    array(size=6)
`0=>
 array(size=4)
'label'=> string 'John'(length=4)
'start'=>
array(size=1)
0=> string '2015-01-17'(length=10)
'end' =>
array(size=1)
0=> string '2015-01-18'(length=10)
'class'=>
array(size=1)
0=> string 'annual'(length=6)
1=>
array(size=4)
 'label'=> string 'John'(length=4)
'start'=>
array(size=1)
0=> string '2015-01-16'(length=10)
'end' =>
array(size=1)
0=> string '2015-01-16'(length=10)
'class'=>
array(size=1)
0=> string 'sick'(length=4)
`

Comment: Are you sure the values are legit?

Comment: yes it is... all values was fetched from the database..
my db is as below
reference_no | name | start_date | end_date  | type     |
1                  | John   |2015-01-17|2015-01-18| annual  |
2                  |John    |2015-01-16|2015-01-16|sick       |
3                  |Peter   |2015-01-02|2015-01-05|annual   |

Comment: Please, check your values, the code is working for me and fits the required structure.

Comment: the code seems okay.$data[] = array(
 'label' => $row["name"] ,
 'start' => array($row["start_date"]),  
 'end'   => array($row["end_date"]),
 'class' => array($row["type"]);

Comment: If the answer was helpful/most convenient, accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data[] = array(
      'label' => $row["name"] ,
      'start' => $row["start_date"], 
      'end'   => $row["end_date"],
      'class' => $row["type"],);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I have already tried that code but its still not what i intended it do display... and the data on this code wasn't sorted.